# How to properly handle empty, null and valid JSON?

Tags: serialization, rust, deserialization, serde

I need to deserialize a JSON file into either `None` or `Some(T)` in Rust. The source we are using will provide `null` or empty, '{}', JSON fields when no values are present. I want to handle both as the `None` case and only deserialize when the JSON field is not null or empty.

```
input: {"test": null} -> output: {"test": None}
input: {"test": {}} -> output: {"test": None}
input: {"test": {"valid_json": 42}} -> output: {"test": {"valid_json": 42}}
```

All of the answers I could find address one case or another but not both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Foo {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "object_empty_as_none")]
    bar: Option<Bar>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Bar {
    inner: u32,
}

pub fn object_empty_as_none<'de, D, T>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Option<T>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
    for<'a> T: Deserialize<'a>,
{
    #[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
    #[serde(deny_unknown_fields)]
    struct Empty {}

    #[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
    #[serde(untagged)]
    enum Aux<T> {
        T(T),
        Empty(Empty),
        Null,
    }

    match Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)? {
        Aux::T(t) => Ok(Some(t)),
        Aux::Empty(_) | Aux::Null => Ok(None),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data = r#"{"bar": null}"#;
    let v: Foo = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(v, Foo { bar: None });

    let data = r#"{"bar": {}}"#;
    let v: Foo = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(v, Foo { bar: None });

    let data = r#"{"bar": {"inner": 42}}"#;
    let v: Foo = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(
        v,
        Foo {
            bar: Some(Bar { inner: 42 })
        }
    );

    let data = r#"{"bar": {"not_inner": 42}}"#;
    let v: Result<Foo, _> = serde_json::from_str(data);
    assert!(v.is_err());
}
```

Should be enough for most case. Remove [`#[serde(deny_unknown_fields)]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#deny_unknown_fields) on `Empty` if you want to.

Comment: for some weird reason, your exact code does not work in my project as it makes a field deserialized with such a function required. Also, in playground removing `deny_unknown_fields` breaks this.

Comment: It seems that we should also cover the case of a field being not present at all, I'll try to post here when I find how

Comment: since edit queue is full, I'll post it here. To be able to deserialize `{}` into `Foo` in this case you'd need to use `#[serde(default, deserialize_with = "object_empty_as_none")]`. There seems to be no way to incorporate that into deserializer itself

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://serde.rs/deserialize-map.html) tells you how to implement a custom map deserializer, which requires customizing how `visit_map` produces key-value pairs from the input data. I've basically copied that page and produced a minimal example that implements what you're looking for. [Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=881914701ecc67b63e0178d7272846e9).

```
use std::fmt;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

use serde::de::{Deserialize, Deserializer, MapAccess, Visitor};
use serde_json::Value as JsonValue;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyMap(HashMap<String, JsonValue>);

impl MyMap {
    fn with_capacity(capacity: usize) -> Self {
        Self(HashMap::with_capacity(capacity))
    }
}

struct MyMapVisitor {
    marker: PhantomData<fn() -> MyMap>,
}

impl MyMapVisitor {
    fn new() -> Self {
        MyMapVisitor {
            marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for MyMapVisitor {
    // The type that our Visitor is going to produce.
    type Value = MyMap;

    // Format a message stating what data this Visitor expects to receive.
    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        formatter.write_str("a very special map")
    }

    // Deserialize MyMap from an abstract "map" provided by the
    // Deserializer. The MapAccess input is a callback provided by
    // the Deserializer to let us see each entry in the map.
    fn visit_map<M>(self, mut access: M) -> Result<Self::Value, M::Error>
    where
        M: MapAccess<'de>,
    {
        let mut map = MyMap::with_capacity(access.size_hint().unwrap_or(0));

        // While there are entries remaining in the input, add them
        // into our map. Empty Objects get turned into Null.
        while let Some((key, value)) = access.next_entry()? {
            let value = match value {
                JsonValue::Object(o) if o.is_empty() => JsonValue::Null,
                _ => value,
            };
            map.0.insert(key, value);
        }

        Ok(map)
    }
}

// This is the trait that informs Serde how to deserialize MyMap.
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for MyMap {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        // Instantiate our Visitor and ask the Deserializer to drive
        // it over the input data, resulting in an instance of MyMap.
        deserializer.deserialize_map(MyMapVisitor::new())
    }
}

fn main() -> serde_json::Result<()> {
    let json_str = r#"{"a": null, "b": {}, "c": {"valid_json": 42}}"#;
    let v: MyMap = serde_json::from_str(json_str)?;
    println!("{:?}", v);
    Ok(())
}
```

This prints `MyMap({"b": Null, "c": Object({"valid_json": Number(42)}), "a": Null})` which I believe is what you're after.